# Issue with class-dump-z "Fail to map * into memory"

Tags: xcode, cydia, theos

I'm using the latest class-dump-z available. 
Followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjFeYk_1HH4

```
iPhone-Pieter:~/dump root# cat class_info 
/*

An exception was thrown while analyzing '/Applications/Calculator.app/' (with sysroot '/'):

DataFile::DataFile(const char*):
    Fail to map "/Applications/Calculator.app/" into memory

*/
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can class dump only mach binary files. You are pointing to the folder that contains the binary file. The correct code would be

> class-dump -H /Applications/Calculator.app/Calculator

The .app is just a container that contains the actual binary file.